# apache localhost href in the javascript

Tags: javascript, apache, firefox, href

I am trying a javascript to change the background of any loaded web page from firefox. I have apache web server installed. I run the below code on any site (for example stackoverflow.com) after the site is loaded run the code separately from the console of the firebug.

```
    var s = document.createElement('link');
    s.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost/new1.css');
    s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    alert('Stylesheet injected!');
```

the content of the `http://localhost/new1.css`

```
   body { background-color: #0000ee !important; }
```

I run the code in the firebug console and the following appears in the head of the html

```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/new1.css">
```

But the new1.css file doesnot load. The background color doesn change. I checked the css rule. it right. I am using firefox and linux OS.

Instead of the `http://localhost/new1.css` i use `https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/new1.css?w=AACLoomOT900PfGVqEuu9rHP4NlewdOq0KaSZbhzmgyG1A&dl=1` in the href and try in firebug it works.

how to check the problem with the localhost server and href and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem,

I have installed noscript addon in firefox it doesnot allow scripts run on other webpages from href localhost. I diabled it. Now everything works fine. I almost struggling for six hours not understanding what wrong.

BUt another problem came is that it works on stackoverflow.com  and wikipidea.com  but not on google.com.

In both the stack and wiki website the sytle sheet appears in the style editor of webdeveloper css sheets. But in google it does not show